# Podcast speed - Can't find adjust button

Tags: podcasts

I have (probably accidentally) changed the speed on my podcasts, so that they are now playing at (I believe) double or 1.5 speed.

I want to change back to normal speed.  I have searched Google for some time, but every 'answer' references a speed button that it meant to be near the 'time bar'.  I can't find any speed (1x or similiar) button anywhere on the podcast screen or in podcast settings.

Help!

Comment: Sorry - managed to find it!!  Thanks everyone.

Comment: It might be helpful for others if you answered your own question using the Answer box below, and posted a screenshot of where it is.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is[image: ![Podcasts app scrennshot]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0MFm.jpg) In Podcasts native app this option is not very accurate, by the way.